# How to restrict a div for on sale products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a div with a specific class that shows the sale percentage of a product that is on sale. But i want to remove this div when the product is not on sale. I don`t know how to write the php code. please help me.

This is my div with php code that works well with on sale products:

```
<div class="pdoffpercent"> <?php echo $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 ); ?> %</div>
```

Comment: follow some tutorials of `php`. Start working with examples to achieve what you want and if you find any problem then post here with your code, error messages and results and we will help you. I know this is a hard work but imagine if all people ask for a snippet of code for their purposes, then the stackoverflow will become code repository, which is not the purpose of stackoverlow ... kindly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved with this snippet:

```
<?php $is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();
 if ( $is_on_sale ) { ?>
 <div class="pdoffpercent">
 %<?php echo $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 ); ?>
</div>
<?php } else{} ?>
```

It`s important to know how to use html in php.